# Add Dynamic Dates to Jquery Air Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How can I add dates dynamically to Air Datepicker. I have a array of Dates `['31-july-2018','10-August-2018','15-August-2018']`. I only want to enable Array Dates and disable remaining dates. How can I achieve this? Below is my fiddle.

Thanks in Advance.

[AirDatepicker Docs](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajat_m/f8edy37t/21/)

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle showing what you have done so far.

Comment: ok, I will create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Solved it. We have a function called onRenderCell in jquery airdatepicker, Which will help you to add content to datepicker before it renders.
I have an Array of Dates **["05-August-2018","10-August-2018","15-August-2018","29-September-2018"]**. By Array of Dates, I rendered Only Specific Dates in Datepicker. **Below is the practical example**.

```
var available_days = ["05-August-2018","10-August-2018","15-August-2018","29- September-2018"];
var months = ['january','feburary','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','November','December'];

$('#my-datepicker').datepicker({
   onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {

     var myDate = ((date.getDate()<10)?'0':'')+date.getDate()+'-'+months[date.getMonth()]+'-'+date.getFullYear();

      if (available_days.indexOf(myDate)>-1) {
        return {
            disabled: false
        }
      } else {
        return {
            disabled: true
       }
     }
   }
 })
```

In the myDate variable, We Set the Date According to Array Format and then in the if section, we compare it with rendering date, If condition satisfy, then it will be rendered, otherwise it will be disabled. Below is the Update Fiddle for that.
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8edy37t/86/)

Thanks.